# Devexpress Xtragrid add button/checkbox/radiobutton type for each cell

Tags: c#, devexpress

I have one grid (xtragrid devxpress for winforms).
The grid has one column and 3 rows.

I want:

```
cell 1 : type button.
cell 2 : type checkboxlist.
cell 3 : type radiobutton,
```

I only found ways to set the Type for column, not for cell.

Comment: i find solution do it with CustomRowCellEdit even but i want when i click button (not in grid, in form), it will add RepositoryItem again.

Comment: You can try this but the best approach is to handle the event which you specified in your comment..